# How to unit-test a pytest plugin's hook acting on session-specific data?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a pytest plugin written to support a hardware-testing process.  The plugin has two key features: a session-scoped `db` fixture that allows tests to write various information to a database, and a `pytest_sessionfinish()` hook that I want to use to update the database with the final `exitstatus` value.

The hook of course does not have access to the fixture; at the moment, this is handled by creating an ad hoc `Session.db` member containing the same object; this is stored by the `db` fixture instantiation code itself.  If there is a better approach to exposing the fixture object to the hook, I'd like to hear about it.

I believe what I have works fine, but I would like to have a unit test for the plugin to verify that the hook calls into the db correctly. I have a `testdir`-based unit test that executes a passing test, but the callback to the db fixture is never made because the Session used inside of `testdir.inline_run()` and passed to the hook is a different Session than the one with the db access object.  And since `pytest_sessionfinish()` is called at the very end of the process, I can't test for this condition within the tests executed by `inline_run()`.

So my question is, how can I verify the call into the fixture from the hook?

Comment: Storing session-scoped data as `session` attributes is IMO fine. As for the unit test, invoke the custom hook directly, passing a session mock, and verify the hook behaviour in isolation. No need to test whether the hook will be invoked - `pytest` tests that already.

Comment: If writing an integration test using `pytester`, there's the `runpytest_subprocess()` which will invoke tests in a separate process.

Comment: @hoefling thank you for that idea for for unit test structure; altho part of what I want to test is that the plugin's hook function is properly declared so that it *is* invoked by pytest. I do know about the `runpytest_subprocess()` call; some of the unit tests in my suite require passing an instance object with hook methods which doesn't mix well with the subprocess model, and if possible I'd rather the unit tests all followed the same pattern.